# How to remove list items depending on predecessor in python

Tags: python, list

Given a Python list, I want to remove consecutive 'duplicates'. The duplicate value however is a attribute of the list item (In this example, the `tuple`'s first element).

Input:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]
```

Desired Output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]
```

Cannot use `set` or `dict`, because order is important.

Cannot use list comprehension `[x for x in somelist if not determine(x)]`, because the check depends on predecessor.

What I want is something like:

```py
mylist = [...]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i-1].attr == mylist[i].attr:
        mylist.remove(i)
```

What is the preferred way to solve this in Python?

Comment: [Python 3.6 maintain dict order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/5168011)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries: How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: Are you only concerned with *consecutive* duplicates? That is, if the last item of the list was also `1, 'a'`, would that be a duplicate of the first?

Comment: What should be the result for `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'a')]` ? Should it be `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'a')]` or `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a')]` ?

Comment: Yes, it's about consecutive duplicates. The output for `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'a')]` should be `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'a')]`.

Comment: Are `(1, 'a')` and `(1, 'b')` considered equal?

Comment: @gmds , yes, `(1, 'a')` and `(1, 'b')` are considered equal duplicates in this case.

Comment: @Sparkofska In that case, you will need to use my solution that specifies a key function to compare only on the first element of the `tuple`.

Comment: @gmds You're right. Accepted and edited example accordingly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` (demonstration with more data):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'a')]

[next(group) for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
```

For completeness, an iterative approach based on other answers:

```
result = []

for first, second in zip(data, data[1:]):
    if first[0] != second[0]:
        result.append(first)

result
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
```

Note that this keeps the *last* duplicate, instead of the first.

Comment: You don't need any key parameter, just take the key of each group

Comment: @yatu The question says "the duplicate value is an attribute of the `list`", which means that that wouldn't work if `(2, 'a')` and `(2, 'b')` are considered equal.

Comment: I see yes in that case indeed it makes sense @gmds. Hard to tell however with this example. IMO if tht was what OP meant a more general example would make more sense

Answer (score 11):

In order to remove consecutive duplicates, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
from itertools import groupby
[tuple(k) for k, _ in groupby(l)]
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 7):

If I am not mistaken, you only need to lookup the last value.

```
test = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'),(3, 'a'),(4,"a"),(4,"a")]

result = []

for i in test:
    if result and i[0] == result[-1][0]: #edited since OP considers (1,"a") and (1,"b") as duplicate
    #if result and i == result[-1]:
        continue
    else:
        result.append(i)

print (result)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to stick to list comprehension, you can use something like this:

```
>>> li = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
>>> [li[i] for i in range(len(li)) if not i or li[i] != li[i-1]]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
```

Please not that `not i` is the pythonic way of writing `i == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]
>>> [v for ix, v in enumerate(data) if not ix or v[0] != data[ix-1][0]]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]
```

Comment: Nice one, because no need for any `import`s. Also `v[0]` can be replaced by any `v.get_attribute()`, which makes it quite universal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd change Henry Yik's proposal a little bit, making it a bit simpler. Not sure if I am missing something.

```
inputList = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
outputList = []
lastItem = None

for item in inputList:
    if not item == lastItem:
        outputList.append(item)
        lastItem = item
print(outputList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily `zip` the list with itself. Every element, except the first one, is zipped with its predecessor:

```
>>> L = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]
>>> list(zip(L[1:], L))
[((2, 'b'), (1, 'a')), ((2, 'b'), (2, 'b')), ((2, 'c'), (2, 'b')), ((3, 'd'), (2, 'c')), ((2, 'e'), (3, 'd'))]
```

The first element is always part of the result, and then you filter the pairs on the condition and return the first element:

```
>>> [L[0]]+[e for e, f in zip(L[1:], L) if e[0]!=f[0]]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat overkill but you can use 'reduce',too:

```
from functools import reduce
data=[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]                                                    
reduce(lambda rslt,t: rslt if rslt[-1][0]==t[0] else rslt+[t], data, [data[0]])                                      
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]
```